# ADAL JS Delegation Scopes

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to provide delegation scopes (i.e. send email) in the [ADAL JS client](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)? If so, where are these defined?

Answer (score 2):

The [ADAL JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) is used for Azure AD 1.0 which uses `resource`, not `scope` to identify the secured resource that the access token can be used to access. See [Azure AD auth code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code).

If you are using Azure AD 2.0 endpoint you'll need to use [MSAL JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) instead.
And in the v2.0 endpoint, it uses `scope` to support the dynamic permission request. For more info, please refer to [v1-v2 comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare#scopes-not-resources).